# git push -u origin local-branch "Error: Repository not found; Fatal: could not read from repository"

Tags: git, github, ssh

I cloned a repository:

```
git clone git@github.com:company/company-repo.git
```

Created my local branch:

```
git checkout -b local-branch
```

Made few changes and committed them:

```
git add .
git commit -m "small changes"
```

And tried to push the newly created local branch to company's git repo:

```
git push -u origin local-branch
```

This is the Error:

```
Error: repository not found
fatal: Could not read from remote repository
please make sure you have correct access rights
and the repository exists
```

What I have tried so far:

- git remote set-url origin git@github.com:company/company-repo.git
- Checked the `.git/config` has the remote `url` parameter:

  url = git@github.com:company/company-repo.git

Note: I have to keep the  url as it is ***WITHOUT*** replacing it with `https` url.

ssh key has been also added:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: Your github path should look like `https://myusername:mypassword@github.com/path_to/myRepo.git`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the newly created repository name with **git remote add origin path**

Comment: you mean newly created BRANCH?

Comment: so for my example : "git remote add origin git@github.com:company/company-repo.git"?  should I run this before git push -u origin local-branch? could u plz edit your answer.